# Random ordering on priority queue

Tags: c++, random, stl

The previous version of my function takes a priority queue(Deque) as input, and then a while loop handles the elements(a self-defined struct) inside. 
Now I want to support the random ordering to see if given a random sequence of input, how's the function perform. What's the best way to do this?

```
struct MyStruct {
  int value;
  // Other members...

  struct Compare {
  bool operator() (const std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>& a, 
                   const std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>& b) const {
    return a->value < b->value; 
  }
  };
};
```

Function:

```
void process(const auto& std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>>& myStructSet) {
  std::priority_queue<shared_ptr<MyStruct>, std::deque<shared_ptr<MyStruct>>,
                            Compare>
      orderedStructs(myStructSet.begin(), myStructSet.end());
  while (!orderedStructs.empty()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

What I want is that if the program has been told to use random ordering, it should create a `randomOrderedStructs` instead, the only difference between the two versions should be the ordering(sequence) inside the deque.

Comment: "Random order" and "`priority_queue`" don't make sense together. The whole point of `priority_queue` is to maintain its elements in a particular order. Stuff your elements into `std::vector`, then `std::shuffle` it.

Comment: I know, but the existing version is using the priority queue. I'm thinking artificially add one more comparator to do the randomness, but despite the complexity of doing that,  the type of the priority queue will be different and I can't reuse the while loop anymore.